# Cluster Layer in Arcgis

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Can someone please help me out of this problem. What's wrong in the above code it will not shows any error but cluster layer not displaying.Remaining features are working.I am using this example https://github.com/nickcam/FlareClusterLayer

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    packages: [{
        name: 'extras',
        location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '') + 'JS/extras'
    }]
};

var findTask, findParams;

ready(function () {
    parser.parse();

    var clusterLayer;

    // registry.byId("ddlDistrict").on("onchange", doFind);
    var intialextent = new Extent(8245227.8765913, 1297819.43274543, 8758703.79511306, 2095175.01113784, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 102100 }));

    var AgricultureBoundary = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://[myserver]/arcgisserver/rest/services/CRD/CRD1/MapServer", {
        opacity: 0.75
    });
    var pointFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://[myserver]/arcgisserver/rest/services/CRD/CRD2/FeatureServer/0", {
        id: "Points"
    });
    map = new Map("mapDiv", {
        center: [77.2, 14],
        zoom: 7,
        extent: intialextent,
        basemap: "streets",
    });

    map.addLayers([AgricultureBoundary, pointFeatureLayer]);

    var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://[myserver]/arcgisserver/rest/services/CRD/CRD2/FeatureServer/0");
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    query.where = "pointcollected  = 'No'";
    query.outFields = ["*"];
    dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", function (featureSet) {
        var inputInfo = {};
        inputInfo.data = dojo.map(featureSet.features, function (feature) {
            var pointX = feature.geometry.x;
            var pointY = feature.geometry.y;
            var att = feature.attributes;
            return { "x": pointX, "y": pointY, "attributes": att };
        });

        clusterLayer = new ClusterFeatureLayer({
            "data": inputInfo.data,
            "distance": 1,
            "id": "clusters",
            "labelColor": "#fff",
            "labelOffset": 10,
            "resolution": map.extent.getWidth() / map.width,
            "singleColor": "#888",
            "singleTemplate": infoTemplate
        });
        var defaultSym = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(4);
        var renderer = new esri.renderer.ClassBreaksRenderer(defaultSym, "clusterCount");
        var blue = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/BluePin1LargeB.png", 32, 32).setOffset(0, 15);
        var green = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/GreenPin1LargeB.png", 64, 64).setOffset(0, 15);
        var red = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/RedPin1LargeB.png", 72, 72).setOffset(0, 15);
        renderer.addBreak(0, 2, blue);
        renderer.addBreak(2, 200, green);
        renderer.addBreak(200, 1001, red);
        clusterLayer.setRenderer(renderer);
        map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the rest of it confirmed to be working properly (e.g. the `queryTask`, basemap display, dynamic and feature layers)?

Comment: All Features working except Cluster.

Comment: Ask the author, file an issue! https://github.com/nickcam/FlareClusterLayer/issues

Comment: Btw. I had some including issues, and the symptoms were exactly as you experience, I found the difference only after debugging in Firebug. Also, I needed to call FeatureClusterLayer's _setMap method explicitely. It's still not working for me, but it might be because I tried to tweak it to work with unsupported data (in other coordinate system + much more complex). I'll continue testing on Monday and perhaps give you the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Passing data in the constructor like that won't do anything (although it probably should handle it).

Try the below instead:

```
dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", function (featureSet) {
    var inputInfo = {};
    inputInfo.data = dojo.map(featureSet.features, function (feature) {
        var pointX = feature.geometry.x;
        var pointY = feature.geometry.y;
        var att = feature.attributes;
        return { "x": pointX, "y": pointY, "attributes": att };
    });

    clusterLayer = new ClusterFeatureLayer({
        "distance": 1,
        "id": "clusters",
        "labelColor": "#fff",
        "labelOffset": 10,
        "resolution": map.extent.getWidth() / map.width,
        "singleColor": "#888",
        "singleTemplate": infoTemplate
    });
    var defaultSym = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(4);
    var renderer = new esri.renderer.ClassBreaksRenderer(defaultSym, "clusterCount");
    var blue = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/BluePin1LargeB.png", 32, 32).setOffset(0, 15);
    var green = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/GreenPin1LargeB.png", 64, 64).setOffset(0, 15);
    var red = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/RedPin1LargeB.png", 72, 72).setOffset(0, 15);
    renderer.addBreak(0, 2, blue);
    renderer.addBreak(2, 200, green);
    renderer.addBreak(200, 1001, red);
    clusterLayer.setRenderer(renderer);
    map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
    clusterLayer.addData(inputInfo.data);
});
```